# How to run RSKj tests?

Tags: java, rsk

I have cloned RSKj from the [official repo](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj) and trying to run the test folder on IntelliJ. I am running the last Java version on an M1 MAC.

I'm having the following error when running the tests on the master branch.

```
Unable to make private static int[]
java.math.BigInteger.add(int[],int[])
accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.math"
to unnamed module @b1a58a3
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How did you run them? Your IDE may use non-local Gradle, so you should run it via

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Make sure Gradle is properly configured via the `./configure.sh` command (one-time operation).
Also, check the Java version. It should work properly on versions 8 (e.g. JVM temurin-1.8) and 11 on M1